# WordPress: Cannot declare class WP_Privacy_Policy_Content

Tags: php, wordpress

WordPress updated the website in October 2020 and it just broke the whole website. This is what I see.

```html
Fatal error: Cannot declare class WP_Privacy_Policy_Content, because the name is already in use in /home/u591757965/domains/ritaenterprises.com/public_html/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-privacy-policy-content.php on line 10
There has been a critical error on your website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.
```

Comment: It looks the error message is obvious - find the second `WP_Privacy_Policy_Content` class and leave in place only one of them.

Comment: Hi Hitesh, could you have a look at the mail that you got from WordPress to see the exact error. As Helvete stated there is a second instance of of a "Class" initiated, but this does not necessarily mean that there are two files. the mail should be titled "Your Site is Exper iencing a Technical Issue" then copy paste the error details into this post as an awnser